# remix run - how to reload all child components of a component loaded through an <Outlet/>

Tags: reactjs, remix.run

I have a component that gets loaded through it's parent's .
This component renders its own components - ActionsBar and Collection.
When the URL changes and the Outlet gets rerendered - my assumption would be that everything within the comonent would get rerendered, however it appears to only rerender the child components if they have changed.

```
export default function ComponentLoadedInOutlet() {
  const collectionData = useLoaderData();
  return (
    <div>
      <ActionsBar />
      <Collection data={collectionData} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

In the above snippet, when the outlet gets reloaded when the URL changes, it is only the Collection component that is being re-rendered because the collectionData has changed.

I would like to know if there's a way to force all the Child components within the outlet to reload, so that I don't have to mess around with resetting lots of state.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your assumption is correct, everything within the component is re-rendered when the url changes. However there is a difference between re-rendering and re-mounting.

When navigating from one url to another which routes to the same component (i.e. a $dynamic.tsx segment), React will merely re-render the component, rather than unmount / mount the component.

This can be useful if you want to preserve state, however this isn't always desirable.

It's therefore common in React to add a `key` prop to reset a component hierarchy.

```js
// /products/$slug.tsx

export const loader = ({ request, params }: LoaderArgs) =>
  json({ slug: params.slug });

export default function ProductDetail() {
  const { slug } = useLoaderData<typeof loader>();
  return (
    // NOTE: `key={slug}`
    <div key={slug}>
      <ActionsBar />
    </div>
  );
}

const ActionsBar = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    // This will re-mount whenever the `slug` changes
    alert("<ActionBar /> mounted");
  }, []);
  return <div>ActionsBar</div>;
};
```

This will tell React to avoid diffing the new tree with the old tree and instead just blow away the old one, creating a brand new tree & therefore mount cycle.

Comment: Scarott .. Thanks, that's exactly what I was after.

Comment: Exactly. Some times it's easy to forget that with Remix, you're still building a React app, so all the rules of React still apply.